# Apply functions on list columns that are not NULL in a tibble in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, purrr

I have a tibble similar to

```
x <- tibble(
   id = 1:2,
   var = list(NULL, tibble(x = c("yes", "no")))
 )
```

I want to apply functions to the list-elements of `var` that are not NULL, e.g.

```
x %>% 
  mutate(var2 = map_chr(var, ~pull(.x) %>% 
                         str_c(., collapse = ";"))
  )
```

This, however, throws an error, as `pull()` cannot be applied to the class "NULL" object in the first row. (It works if I filter before, but I cannot drop cases where `var` is NULL as other variables contain values for such cases).

I failed to restrict the operation to rows where `var` is not NULL.

The following does not work, for example:

```
x %>% 
  mutate(
    var2 = case_when(
      !map_lgl(var, is.null) ~ map_chr(var, ~pull(.x) %>% 
                                          str_c(., collapse = ";"))))
```

I'd be grateful for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option where you unnest your column and then within group collapse your variable:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

x %>% 
  unnest(var, keep_empty = T) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(var2 = str_c(x, collapse = ";"), .groups = "drop")
```

**Output**

```
     id var2  
  <int> <chr> 
1     1 NA    
2     2 yes;no
```